# How to pass { useUnifiedTopology: true } to my unique Node.Js Mongoclient constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, web, backend

I was wondering how I could add the useUnifiedtopology property to my MongoClinet constructor. It should be an easy fix, just fitting it into the constructor, but the "constructor" I use does not have a "new" keyword and is not formatted the same as the documentation prefers (even though all constructors should have a "new" keyword), though everything still works perfectly fine. Here is my setup code (Node.Js, Express, MongoDB, no Mongoose):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
const url = "insertYourUrlHere"
```

Comment: *Does* that work? You require MongoDB twice and never call anything.

Comment: It should be `mongodb=require("mongodb"); {  MongoClient } = mongodb` or just `{MongoClient} = require("mongodb")`

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const {MongoClient}=require("mongodb")

const url = "insertYourUrlHere"
const client = new MongoClient(url, options, callback)
```

Options could be your object:

```
{
useUnifiedTopology:true,
useNewUrlParser:true
}
```

You can omit `callback`. In this case it returns a promise, and you may use `try/catch` or `.then().catch()` to handle it.

Sources: [MongoDB example](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database) and [Native Driver Docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html)

---

**Further details**

Once you import `MongoClient` you can either:

1. instantiate it using `new MongoClient(uoc)`

*or*

2. `MongoClient.connect(uoc)`.